# Switch current flow from A to B based on C's status

Tags: flow-control

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKxYDc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Hello everyone,
I want the current to flow from A to B if the switch is pressed. What can I do here?

Total newbie here.

Thank you.

EDIT 1: Can't move the switch.

Comment: Do you have a power source that can drive a relay?

Comment: Yes. But something quiet would be really nice. @BrianDrummond

Comment: A transistor with pull-up to the gate?

Comment: @winny Could you give a schematic?

Comment: so, SMNK, what things *do* you have access to? Also, what's your state of understanding of transistors? Just the schematic might not help you much.

Comment: Also, without knowing what gets attached to B, it's unlikely we can actually suggest something that works all the time.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I just know that transistors control the current passing from collector to emitter based on base's status. The B is gonna be powering an UA741 IC and a 12V lamp.

Comment: @SMNK how much power will the lamp draw?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Really sorry. My bad the B is just gonna power the IC.

Comment: @SMNK If C powers  the IC, pressing the switch will short this power supply to ground...

Comment: Sorry again B powers the IC. C is connected to switch. @Huisman

Comment: It is frustrating for us to play guessing games like this and tease details out from you one detail at a time. It would have been better if you drew the WHOLE CIRCUIT from the beginning, including the UA741 AND the things attached to the UA741. Anyway, your best bet appears to be a high-side PMOS switch between A and B.

Comment: @mkeith You are totally right. My bad, The question is for a friend whose english is not good enough. So I gotta get the info from him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcRb63.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Rewire the switch as shown.*

I assume that there is some reason you don't want to do this but you haven't explained it in your question.

---

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fadLPE.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. (a) The simplest - unlikely to go wrong - solution. (b) A simple, no-component solution.*

This is really hard to beat. Automotive relays come in insulated enclosures, take standard crimp terminals and are very robust.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. But cant access the switch. @Transistor

Comment: So what is on B? How much current? What is the application?

Comment: A UA741 IC. @Transistor

Comment: @SMNK? But why? It’s one of the worst op-amps.

Comment: See the update.

Comment: Would figure 2b not yield an unstable opamp that bounces in the rhythm of the key?

Comment: @Huisman, we have no idea what the OP is at. It's no worse than putting the switch in the positive unless the load is grounded in which case it will probably blow.

Answer (score 1):

This should solve it.

Feel free to substitute the transistor to any suitable P-MOSFET.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5c5zW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You beat me to it.

Comment: Comment for the OP: generally bad things can happen if you apply voltage to any of the inputs or outputs of the 741 when its 12V supply is de-energized. Since you haven't shown what is connected to the 741, I am not sure whether this is an issue for your circuit or not.

Comment: @mkeith I've never found another site, save for Amibay perhaps, where you need to be _reeeealy_ trigger happy to get anything done than this one.

Comment: @mkeith 741 is junk by most standards, but your comment is valid for many op-amps.

Comment: I didn't intend for my comment to apply to the 741 only. It was supposed to be a general concept for all IC's. Applying voltage to inputs of IC's when the supply rail is at 0V usually violates the abs max ratings. Of course, there may be input diodes so applying voltage to an input may power up the rail through the input diodes. All this business is best avoided by design.

Comment: Saying that the 741 is junk is like saying the model T is a piece of junk.

Comment: @mkeith If you need it in work as your primary means of transportation, it is. I’m sure some audiophile can tell you all about the crisp-yet-warm sound from the 741 as well as some people enjoy their Model T for a Sunday drive.

Comment: I am merely saying that the historical context is relevant. I would never use a 741 in a new design. But I have a lot of respect for it. So I prefer to think of it as outdated rather than junk.